# [R]How to extract multiple points based on polygons

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a polygon file and a point file (gpkg file)
Within the area of the polygon, there are several point files.
How can I extract only the points that exist in the area of the polygon?
The language used is assumed to be the R sf package.

The sample data is as follows.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vzyStvbSWYiqj7Yu-Te4sPHlZlxscAlE/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1StzjcogZAS3gxy9owxKNZWOZFf1LoI1o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! I think you may want to check https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/, in particular, chapters 1 to 4 or 5

Comment: Thank you for your comments!!
it was solved by st_intersection()